# General solution to linear system with general form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find the general solution of the system 
$$X' = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}X$$

where $a+d \not= 0 $ and $ad-bc=0$
I find that the eigenvalues are 0 and $a+d$ with corresponding eigenvectors both $[0,0]$ which implies that the general solution is simply $X(t)=0$ but this solution does not seem right to me. Is there something I have done wrong?

Comment: If the matrix $A$ is singular, then $0$ is guaranteed to be (at least) one of the eigenvalues.

Comment: I found that 0 is one of its eigenvalues but also that a+d is also an eigenvalue

Comment: "with corresponding eigenvectors both $[0,0]$" <-- That can't be right, because by definition eigenvectors have to be nonzero vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given

$$X' = \begin{bmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d
  \end{bmatrix}X\\\text{where}~ ~~a+d \ne 0 , ~~ad-bc=0$$

We can find the eigenvalues using the characteristic polynomial by solving $|A - \lambda I| = 0$, yielding

$$\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{a^2-2 a d+4 b c+d^2}+a+d\right),\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-2 a d+4 b c+d^2}+a+d\right)$$

We can then find the associated eigenvectors by solving $[A-\lambda_i]v_i = 0$, yielding

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    -\dfrac{\sqrt{a^2-2 a d+4 b c+d^2}-a+d}{2 c}\\1
  \end{pmatrix}, v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{-\sqrt{a^2-2 a d+4 b c+d^2}-a+d}{2 c}\\1\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, we can use the conditions we are given, namely $a+d \not= 0 ,ad-bc=0 $, by substituting $bc = ad$ in each eigenvalue/eigenvector pair yielding

$$\lambda_1 = 0, v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{d}{c}  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} \\ \lambda_2 = a + d , v_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{a}{c} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

We can now write

$$X(t) = c_1~ e^{\lambda_1 t} ~v_1 + c_2 ~e^{\lambda_2 t}~ v_2 = c_1 \begin{pmatrix} -\dfrac{d}{c}  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + c_2~ e^{(a+d)t} \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{a}{c} \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$